# How to Vertically Stretch a Block of Text?

Tags: scaling, text-manipulation

Is it possible to stretch text vertically?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\scalebox{1}[3]{hello}
```

Answer (score 11):

As David already stated in his answer the standard package `graphicx` provides the macro `\scalebox{<h-factor>}[<v-factor>]{<content>}` for this. The [`grfguide`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/grfguide) manual explains this and similar macros in detail. One thing to remember is that the content is boxes as horizontal box, so it can't include line breaks etc. except if you include a `minipage`, `\parbox` or similar construct.

There is also the `\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<content>}` which allows to scale text to a specific width and/or height. Use `!` for the dimension you don't want to specify but to scale according to the other dimension. The starred version `\resizebox*` will scale the `totalheight` instead (height+depth).

There is also the [`adjustbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/adjustbox) package which extends `graphicx` by providing a general key=value interface. Using this package you can scale even complicated content easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\adjustbox{scale={2}{3}}{Text}

\adjustbox{width=\linewidth}{Text}

\adjustbox{minipage=10cm,scale={2}{3}}{Text\\with\\multiple\\lines}

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=10cm,scale={2}{3}}
    Text\\
    with\\
    multiple\\
    lines
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, because it also gives alternatives and explanations.

Comment: Is there a way to iterate over the separate lines, to add a new \scalebox for each line?  In different contexts, I would like to layout the same exact text differently, though with the line breaks intact.

Comment: @elikakohen: If you want different scaling for each line, you need to place `\scalebox` for each manually. You still can place the linebreaks outside the scaleboxes.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to figure out how to do the delineation for it - so I will post a new question.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

In ConTeXt

```
\scale[sx=1,sy=2]{Some Text}
```