# Vectorized Text Effects/Transformations: Stretching & Expanding (WordArt)

Tags: text-decorations, text-manipulation

I'd like to apply a text transformation similar to what the [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) extension 'Modify Path -> Envelope' does within LaTeX:

[image: inkscape text effect transform vectorized text to fit to box]

In-source documentation of the envelope extension:

> This extension implements Bezier enveloping. It takes an arbitrary
>   path (the "letter") and a 4-sided path (the "envelope") as input. The
>   envelope must be 4 segments long. Unless the letter is to be rotated
>   or flipped, the envelope should begin at the upper left corner and be
>   drawn clockwise.

Presumably this can only be done with one of the more advanced drawing packages:

- [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) (pgf/tikz library decorations.text, basic layer canvas transformation)
- [pstricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks) (possibly based on `\psWarp` form `pst-text` (v.1.01) together with a postscript font)
- [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/)
- [MetaPost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html)

Comment: So you want an example with Tikz? Where is the question?

Comment: @percusse: thanks for catching up. the question is: transforming the text having an envelope which is not just a rectangle (see the second picture). My answer works only for the simpler case. I am happy with tikz, but other tools are equally good. I don't have a preference

Answer (score 3):

Needs work (and not a TiKZ `text effect`):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz, mult]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (o) at (0,0);
    \def\j{o}
    \foreach \i [count=\ino] in {T,E,X,T,-,E,F,F,E,C,T}
      {
        \node (\ino) [scale=\ino*\ino, right=0pt of \j, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] {\i};
        \global\let\j\ino
      }
    \path [draw] (1.north east) -- (\j.north west) -| (\j.south east) -- (\j.south west) -- (1.south west) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: text-effect]

Answer (score 2):

The question [Stretching text vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67254/stretching-text-vertically) offers a solution for applying a rectangular envelope, so to speak:

Using `\scalebox{⟨h-scale⟩}[⟨v-scale⟩]{⟨text⟩}` of the package `graphics` (`$ texdoc grfguide`):

```
   \documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
   \usepackage{graphics}
   \begin{document}
   HELLO\\[1ex]
   \scalebox{2}[1]{HELLO}
   \end{document}
```

[image]