# How to globally stretch text height, keeping the margin limits?

Tags: scaling, text, height, adjustbox

I am working with a designer that requires the height of the font type we are using to be stretched by a factor of 1.2. I have succeeded doing so using the `adjustbox` package, as described in the post [Stretching text vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67254/stretching-text-vertically)

I have however two questions with this approach:

1. I would like to set this globally, to all text in the document. I
   was wondering what would be the way to make this behaviour propagate
   in such manner?
2. When using the adjustbox approach the text overflows the margins
   of the document. Is there any way to prevent it from doing so and
   respect the margins?

Here I add an example of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
% "stretch" the font by a factor of 1.2
\adjustbox{scale={1}{1.2}}{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want to stretch? The height of the glyphs? Maybe you should use another font then. If you simply want to increase the font size there are packages/options for this.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you call "the adjustbox approach". E.g., with which options and settings is `\adjustbox` called?

Comment: @TeXnician: Yes, I mean the height of the glyphs. I don't seek for font size as a whole, I need to stretch just the height.

Comment: @Mico: Please see in my edited question what I mean.

Comment: Are you sure that they want to stretch  the glyph height instead of the baseline skip?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ask the type designer to stretch all glyphs -- vertical axis only -- by 20%? Is something preventing the designer from doing just that?

Comment: Late response, sorry. We already have tried to change the glyphs, but is not an ideal solution since we are dealing with numerous fonts, and is cumbersome to alter each one of them. I was hoping to find a general solution by changing all of them in LaTeX.

Comment: There would be the possibility to scale the whole page vertically, i.e. create it smaller in height, than stretch it later. This can be done in TeX or maybe with some PDF tool. However, this stretches also images etc., which might be shrunk down beforehand. It all depends on the exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

As the package author of `adjustbox` let me tell you that it is not intended to vertically stretch whole paragraphs of text, even if it handles that task well. Scaling text is frowned upon in general. Anyway, keep it mind that `adjustbox` works on *boxes*, i.e. horizontal material, and therefore its content does not get line breaks! If you want these then you need to wrap them into a `\parbox` or `minipage` first. For this `adjustbox` gives you the `minipage` key!

See below an example on how to avoid the spilling into the margin.
Adding it to every paragraph in a whole document is not possible.

I would recommend to look for another solution, e.g. stretch the font, change to a different font or maybe change the designer...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\bigskip

% "stretch" the font by a factor of 1.2
\noindent\adjustbox{minipage=\linewidth,scale={1}{1.2}}{\blindtext}

\bigskip

% or better use the environment version:
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,scale={1}{1.2}}
\blindtext
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```